# Twitter : Cannot deserialize a JSON array into an object because the type requires a JSON object

Tags: c#, json.net, tweetsharp

I am using TweetSharp to retrieve tweets which in turn uses JSON.NET by Newtonsoft. And this is the app code, very simple.

```
ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions =
    new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions();
listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions.ScreenName = "MarilynDenisCTV";
listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions.IncludeRts = false;

var tweets = twitterService.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(listTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions).Take(50);
```

There is one tweet that is giving me trouble. And the Exception I am getting is in this line of code in TweetSharp source.

```
public virtual object DeserializeJson(string content, Type type)
{
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(content))
    {
       using (var jsonTextReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader))
       {
           return _serializer.Deserialize(jsonTextReader, type);
       }
    }
}
```

This is the exception I am getting

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'TweetSharp.TwitterStatus' because the type requires a JSON 

object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a 

type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. 

JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '',
```

I downloaded the latest source from TweetSharp, but that doesn't seem to help, any ideas why? One more thing, the one problem tweet starts with [{"created_at": "Sun Nov 03 21:44:51 +0000 2013", as supposed to {"created_at": "Sun Nov 03 21:44:51 +0000 2013", it has the extra square bracket.

Comment: Seems like you know what the problem is then ...the extra "[". Either remove it (you have the string), or write to them to complain they didn't cover an end case...

Comment: well, Tweetsharp is no longer supported. So I am going to have to remove the extra [. But I am curious to see why others haven't experienced the same problem and why only that one tweet is giving problems in particular

Comment: I have the same problem. But I read also that TweetSharp stopped its development since 2.3.1. (as you know) So if any changes occurred on the Twitter API since that last release. You will have to change library. Which s*cks because its the second library that I am using which does that. First Twitter2lite and now Tweetsharp, aargh (see my frustration)

Comment: Try TweetInvi. That is the new one i am experimenting with

Comment: @doglin an old post but I have just ran into this issue, I inherited a project which originally was outsourced. Tweets stopped working, So it was left to me to fix. I understood the error, but tricky to fix... 2 hours on, still don't have it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, through some investigation, i was able to dig into the source code of TweetSharp while debugging my application.

The reason, that the JSON Deserializer is throwing exception in my case,  is because some users twitted emoji cons in their tweets, like smiley faces, sad faces. Those emoji cons are NOT encoded, before passing to JSON, hence that is what is breaking the JSON Deserailizer.

I didn't have the time to make any changes to the Tweetsharp code, since at work we are in the process of switching to another library. Content team just removed those tweets that had badly encoded emoji cons. That was a quick and dirty fix

Comment: We solved it by checking out the source code and building itself and newer version of JSON deserializer. Seems to not cause any problems but doesn't matter anymore because we decided to go for our own API implentation. Second time a twitter library that we were using is being deperecated.

Comment: @IanS. Did you push a commit? If so where can I grap a copy? Or could you possible explain the change(s) necessary? I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: @doglin Which library did you guys end up using? Thanks.

Comment: @Paul I'm not sure that I did, however I'm not the OP, so maybe you shoul direct the question at them as they may have a solution. It was a long time ago, but I think in the end I just did some try / catch clauses so that any tweets causing issues were just discarded.

Comment: @PhillHealey thanks for the reply. That's exactly what I have ended up doing. It seemed to be any issue with a certain tweet that had s reply connected to it, so I've set the exclude replies to true and wrapped it in a try catch to be safe. Not ideal but seems to work ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Paul No problem. Come to think of it, I think replies might have been the issue for us too. Or maybe it was ones with an image attached. Eitherway, glad it's sorted for you.